# Multiplication AbstractInteger

Tags: haskell, integer, multiplication

I have a datatype:

```
data AbstractInteger = Zero
                     | Succ AbstractInteger
                     | Pred AbstractInteger
                     deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I already have two functions:

1) Convert AbstractInteger into Integer:

```
aiToInteger :: AbstractInteger -> Integer
aiToInteger (Zero) = 0
aiToInteger (Succ next) = 1 + (aiToInteger next)
aiToInteger (Pred prev) = (aiToInteger prev) - 1
```

2) Addition AbstractInteger :

```
plusAbs :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
plusAbs a b | aiToInteger a == 0 = b
            | aiToInteger b == 0 = a
            | aiToInteger a > 0 = (Succ (plusAbs (Pred a) b))
            | otherwise = (Pred (plusAbs (Succ a) b))
```

But I don't understand how to create multiply function.

I wrote this but it's not work.

```
multiplyAbs :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
multiplyAbs _ (Zero) = (Zero)
multiplyAbs (Zero) _ = (Zero)
multiplyAbs a (Succ Zero) = a
multiplyAbs (Succ Zero)  b = b
multiplyAbs a b = (plusAbs a (timesAbs a (Pred(b))))
```

Comment: You could exploit `plusAbs`, implementing multiplication as repeated addition. You can not use `+` on your own custom integers.

Comment: @chi yeah it's mistake and I already fix it but it still not work

Comment: I would encourage you to implement `plusAbs` without using `aiToInteger` to get a better feel for how your data type actually works.

Comment: Doing a recursive call with a larger argument often leads to a non terminating function. You should remove constructors from arguments, not adding them. You need to handle the case `multiplyAbs (Succ a) b = ...` and `multiplyAbs (Pred a) b = ...`. For the latter you would need a subtraction subroutine, or at least an "opposite" subroutine (which is easier to implement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've implemented `aiToInteger`, you might want to implement `iToAi`, something like:

```
iToAi :: Integer -> AbstractInteger
iToAi a | a == 0 = Zero
        | a < 0 = Pred (iToAi (a + 1))
        | a > 0 = Succ (iToAi (a - 1))
```

Then `plusAbs` and `multiplyAbs` will come down to converting abstract integers to integers, perform the operations on them and convert them back:

```
plusAbs' :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
plusAbs' a b = iToAi (aiToInteger a + aiToInteger b)

multiplyAbs' :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
multiplyAbs' a b = iToAi (aiToInteger a * aiToInteger b)
```

But I'd suggest trying to implement the functions by using pattern-match on the arguments, something like:

```
negative :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
negative Zero = Zero
negative (Succ a) = Pred (negative a)
negative (Pred a) = Succ (negative a)

multiplyAbs :: AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger -> AbstractInteger
multiplyAbs Zero a = Zero
multiplyAbs (Succ a) b = plusAbs (multiplyAbs a b) b
multiplyAbs (Pred a) b = plusAbs (multiplyAbs a b) (negative b)
```

The key point is that `Succ a` can be associated with `(a + 1)`, that's why `(Succ a) * b` can be associated with `a * b + b`. According to this logic `(Pred a) * b` is converted to `a * b - b`, that's why you need `negative` function here.

`plusAbs` is implemented similarly:

- `(a + 1) + b` is the same as `1 + (a + b)`
- `(a - 1) + b` is the same as `(a + b) - 1`

The logic is just like in your example, but you can avoid using `aiToInteger` by using pattern-match.